# Migrate MongoDB 2.4.14 to MongoDB 3.6

Tags: mongodb, migration, mongodb-3.6, mongodb2.4

I have a database with MongoDB 2.4.14 and I want to migrate the database to MongoDB 3.6.

Note: the file is original from the db path. Not from `mongodump`.

This process is messy as it requires doing so on many of our clients.

Any advice will be welcomed as I'm a bit lost in this process.